# Invite and share app data between android devices

Tags: android, synchronization, shared

I´m trying to develop my first Android app. It´s basically a score counter. My idea is to add a functionality like other apps like Wunderlist:

1) User A and user B have the app installed in their devices.

2) User A create a game score with two players (stored in xml format).

3) User A sends an invitation to user B to share this game score (maybe using its google account).

4) User B receives the invitation/notification and accept it.

5) Both users share the score, they can change it, and the score is updated in both devices every time it´s changed, so that both users have the same score.

6) If the score is deleted, the app send a notification to delete it in the other device.

In Wunderlist app, for example, you can create a list and invite someone to share the list. There is a lot of Android apps, like production apps, that share information this way.

¿How can I implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can share data by use: internet connection, bluetooth. or LAN wifi connection. With internet connection you have to build a server side module to receive and transfer data.

Comment: Check out [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) - easy to implement client side code for updates etc. Otherwise, you could update per Bluetooth etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is very general, but I will try to answers as detailed as I can. First of all you will need a server which every user will be connecting. You can create connection between users with e.g. bluetooth, but it's only working on short distance as you may know.

**Answer:**

Every files should be stored in server, so you can send to your server data in JSON format which is very simple to implement. Then server can create push notifications to user which first user want to connect. The main idea is that every client have to create connection with server in order to receive push notifications.

In my humble opinion, the best solution in such case is Google Cloud Messaging, which sends server data to users devices.

Comment: ThisMartian got the gyst. There is much more complexity regarding this simple sharing problem. What if a user deletes the file outside of your app on his/her device? What if both users edit the file at the same time? What if the user is changing the file without internet connection?

All of these problems are simplified by having a file on the server to use as a point of reference. Then you implement your logic to solve the special cases I mentioned above, but the basic idea is to always compare user file against the one on the server.

Comment: I think that Google Cloud Messaging is exactly what I was looking for. I´ll try to look for more information and any example to implement it. 
The idea for this functionality is to use it when I play online with my friends, and the score won´t be updated frecuently, so although I have clear that I have to implement some logic for those cases, I think that it won´t be a source of frecuent problems.

If I can make it work, I will put the code if it can help someone.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is detail, but came to my mind. Fast and simple solution for different stages of file. You can simply add to the file an Integer representing current revision of file. It could be auto-incrementing Integer and in that way you can comparing different files.